# Can the full set of 100 shofar blasts be performed by more than 1 person?

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

One person made the bracha and blew some blasts. Then, for some reason, he is physically unable to blow the rest. Can someone else complete the job?

Does it matter if the switch happens in the middle of a group - say a person blows just t'kiah / shevarim but can't do the clsoing t'kiah of the group

vs.

1st person completes 1 set of tki'ah-shevarim-t'kiah but there are 2 more such groups (as in the case of the 1st 40 blasts done before Musaph)

vs.

1st person completed the full set of the 1st 40 before Musaph, and 2nd person completes all the other blasts beginning with the sets done during Musaph repetition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Talmud (RH 34) records:

> שמע תשע תקיעות בתשע שעות ביום יצא מט' בני אדם כאחד [לא יצא] תקיעה מזה ותרועה מזה יצא
>   If he heard 9 blasts at 9 hours of the day, he fulfilled his obligation. [If he heard them] from 9 people at once, he did not fulfill his obligation, [but if] there was a Tekia from this [person] and [then] a Terua from this [person] he does fulfill his obligation. (my translation)

The Rambam (Shofar 3:6) and Shulchan Arukh (OC 588:2) rule accordingly. Thus switching in all your cases would be allowed.